# mod_wsgi fails under pressure

Tags: python, linux, mod-wsgi

I tried to stress my server a little, and something weird happened. I'm using mod_wsgi, with basic script plugged in:

```
import socket

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                    ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [output]
```

I tried to stress it a little with simple "hit it all I can":

```
#!/bin/zsh

for i in {1..50}
do
wget http://$this_site/ &
done
```

And weird thing happened - wget thrown at me reports about error 500 on server.

when I checked out  apache logs, this is what I found

```
[Sat Mar 10 21:46:18 2012] [error] [client 95.49.81.25] mod_wsgi (pid=23632): Target WSGI script '/home/tricky/www/run.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Mar 10 21:46:18 2012] [error] [client 95.49.81.25] mod_wsgi (pid=23632): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/tricky/www/run.py'.
[Sat Mar 10 21:46:18 2012] [error] [client 95.49.81.25] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Mar 10 21:46:18 2012] [error] [client 95.49.81.25]   File "/home/tricky/www/run.py", line 1, in <module>
[Sat Mar 10 21:46:18 2012] [error] [client 95.49.81.25]     import web
[Sat Mar 10 21:46:18 2012] [error] [client 95.49.81.25]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web.py-0.36-py2.7.egg/web/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
[Sat Mar 10 21:46:18 2012] [error] [client 95.49.81.25]     import utils, db, net, wsgi, http, webapi, httpserver, debugerror
[Sat Mar 10 21:46:18 2012] [error] [client 95.49.81.25]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web.py-0.36-py2.7.egg/web/wsgi.py", line 8, in <module>
[Sat Mar 10 21:46:18 2012] [error] [client 95.49.81.25]     import http
[Sat Mar 10 21:46:18 2012] [error] [client 95.49.81.25] ImportError: No module named http
```

How is this possible? And why is it happening?

Comment: The error states that your wswgi script imports web, and the web module depends on http module, which is not found in the system

Comment: And, this, does not happen under 'normal' load?

Comment: The tricky part is, under normal load everything works just fine...

Comment: If you found a solution yourself, post it as answer and accept it please.

Comment: Oh, you're right @webjunkie :) it's done :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution - apache2 had some weird race-state after messing with it's configuration. After `service apache2 restart` everything went back to normal :)